# how do i get raw image data from a blob:url?

Tags: html, image, blob

i want to save an image stored at a blob:url to a server but i cant work out how to extract the raw data from the blob URL.

live demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dom-camera-experiments-mjtii

the image is coming from a camera package (though could be from anywhere). ive added some console output to see whats happening in the following code:

```
        onTakePhoto={(blobURL) => {
          console.log("blob", blobURL);
          new Response(blobURL).arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
            let data = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            console.log("blob typed arrayBuffer", data.length, data);

            // data is only 63 bytes in length?  
          });
        }}
```

The array buffer length for the image blob is 63 so i think this is not the entire image file but i dont know how to access it. How do i access the raw data at the blobURL?

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches work but i found this the most straightforward:

```
fetch(blobURL)
  .then((response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    blob.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
      const array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
      // do anything with the byte array here
    }
  })
}
```